# Symfony2 and Bootstrap slider

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, symfony, symfony-forms

I'm trying to make this good Bootstrap slider (https://github.com/seiyria/bootstrap-slider) work on Symfony2.

To do this I created a custom form field type following the indications here (http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html).

So I have my custom form field type like this:

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/SingleSliderType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;

class SingleSliderFormType extends AbstractType
{
    public function configureOptions(OptionsResolver $resolver)
    {
        $resolver->setDefaults(array(
            'choices' => array(
                '0' => 0,
                '1' => 20,
                '2' => 40,
                '3' => 60,
                '4' => 80,
                '5' => 100,
            )
        ));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'choice';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'singleslider';
    }
}
```

I created a fields.html.twig and this is the content:

```
{% block singleslider_widget -%}
    <div class="input-group">
            <input type="text" class='singleslider' data-slider-min="0" data-slider-max="100" data-slider-step="5" {% if value is defined %} data-slider-value="{{ value }}"{% endif %}/>
    </div>
{%- endblock singleslider_widget %}
```

Of course the above is barebone as I'm not setting the real choices, it was just the start to see if it worked...and it does not, hence I'm here.

This is what I do in the form type calling it:

```
$builder->add($fieldName, new SingleSliderFormType(), array('label'=>'Risk', 'required' => $req, 'choices'   => $percentages, 'attr'=>array('class'=>'singleslider '.$cssClass), 'label_attr'=>array('class'=>$cssClass)) );
```

$percentages is simply an array like ['0'=>'0%', '5'=>'5%'...]

When I retrieve info from DB all is fine and mapped properly on the slider. When I move the slider a blank string is passed, hence it does not work.

The original field (where I store the info) is an integer.

What am I missing?

I've also tried to declare that it extends 'text' instead of 'choice' in the getParent(), but it complains that: `"The option "choices" does not exist. Known options are:..."`. But isn't that one of the purposes of the setDefaults, declaring a new option type AND setting it's default value?

I'm stuck and puzzled :/

EDIT: new version after comments.

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/Type/SingleSliderType.php
namespace AppBundle\Form\Type;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver;
use Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface;

class SingleSliderFormType extends AbstractType
{
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setOptional(array(
        'choices' => array(
            '0' => 0,
            '1' => 20,
            '2' => 40,
            '3' => 60,
            '4' => 80,
            '5' => 100,
        )
    ));
}

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'text';
    }

    public function getName()
    {
        return 'singleslider';
    }
}
```

now I have the error `"Warning: Illegal offset type"` and this is the point 2 of the error stack:

```
at ErrorHandler ->handleError ('2', 'Illegal offset type', 'D:\provarepos\user\vendor\symfony\symfony\src\Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolver.php', '337', array('optionNames' => array('choices' => array('0', '20', '40', '60', '80', '100')), 'option' => array('0', '20', '40', '60', '80', '100'), 'this' => object(OptionsResolver))) 
in vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/OptionsResolver/OptionsResolver.php at line 337
```

EDIT 2:

Managed to make it work by substituting the `setOptional` with `setDefaults`.

The problem of returning blank is the same. I even try to destroy the slider, and I have a simple text object, but when I save the form it does not bind the value on DB. Needless to say that if I use the original choice field it works. I also tried to force calling the setter for the field, by specifying the by_reference = false, and then inside the entity I did:

```
public function setRiskToleranceFlag($riskToleranceFlag)
{
    $this->riskToleranceFlag = intval($riskToleranceFlag);

    return $this;
}
```

All to no avail as you can imagine.

Answer (score 2):

A simple way to use this bootstrap-slider with Symfony without creating a custom form field is to create a text field and pass the slider's attributes in the "attr" option.

```
$formBuilder->add($question->getId(), TextType::class, array(
            'required' => true,
            'label' => $label,
            'attr' => [
                'data-provide' => 'slider',
                'data-slider-ticks' => '[1, 2, 3]',
                'data-slider-ticks-labels' => '["1", "2", "3"]',
                'data-slider-min' => '1',
                'data-slider-max' => '3',
                'data-slider-step' => '1',
                'data-slider-value' => '2',
                'data-slider-tooltip' => 'hide'
            ]
        ));
```

Comment: Thank you for your time. I don't know if the solution works but if it does it's a fine one ;-)

Comment: You're welcome! It works fine, I'm using it in the project I'm currently working on.

Answer (score 0):

Use `setDefaultOptions`instead of `configureOptions`

```
public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setOptional([
        'choices' => array(
            '0' => 0,
            '1' => 20,
            '2' => 40,
            '3' => 60,
            '4' => 80,
            '5' => 100,
        )
    ]);
}
```

It should solve your problem

Comment: I suppose removing the configureOptions function (and indeed I found out that it was introduced in Symfony 2.7 while I'm on 2.6). Anyways it gives me "Compile Error: Declaration of AppBundle\Form\Type\SingleSliderFormType::setDefaultOptions() must be compatible with Symfony\Component\Form\FormTypeInterface::setDefaultOptions(Symfony\Component\OptionsResolver\OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)"

Comment: you forgot the parameter of the setDefaultOptions : `setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)` don't forget to use the OptionResolverInterface in the top of your file too

Comment: I had forgot the "use" on top. Now I have it and have a new fantastic error (see edited question). Thank you a lot for your time!